# How to read from std::cin until the end of the stream?

Tags: c++, iostream, stdin, eof, io-redirection

My problem is, that I want to read the input from `std::cin` but don't know how long the input is. Also I have to `char` and can't use `std::string`.
There are two ways I have to handle:
a) The user inputs text and when he hits [ENTER] the program stops reading.
b) The user redirects `std::cin` to a file (like `.\a.oput < file`) which can hold multiple lines.

**Edit:** Just noticed that std::cin.eof() is always false also in the case of reading form a file.

For a) I could read until \n occures. For b) **Edit: No** (I could read until std::cin.eof() occures.)
But when I don't know whether I'm getting an a) or a b) problem, how can I break the reading process?

This is what I have for a) ...

```
char buffer = ' ';
while(std::cin >> std::noskipws >> buffer && buffer != '\n')
{
    // do some stuff with buffer
}
```

... and b)

```
char buffer = ' ';
while(std::cin >> std::noskipws >> buffer)
{
    // do some stuff with buffer
}
```

Also I know there is `std::cin.tellg()` to get the current position in the stream.

**Edit:** So it seems like in case of the file the input streams gets terminated, in the way that `std::cin >> std::noskipws >> buffer` gets `false`.
What the code above does for a):

- It waits for the user to make an input and press [ENTER]
- Then it loops through every char entered by the user on the last line.
- Then it waits again for the user to make an input and press [ENTER]
- Infinite-waiting-processing-loop

So how do I do it?

Comment: Tell us why you can't use `std::string`. Perhaps we can help you with that problem, too.

Comment: For non-standard code you can use `kbhit()` in `conio.h`

Comment: @Rob It's from an exercies and we don't 'know' `std::string` yet.
Neither can we use non-standard code.
What I'm asking is not directly required in the exercies, but I'm just curious...

Comment: I would strongly recommend just redesigning out of this requirement. A program's input interface should be consistent. If it's a single line, it should be a single line. If it's read to end of file, it should be read to end of file. For non-portable code, there's `isatty`, but better would be an option flag to set the mode if absolutely needed.

Comment: why not combining the two conditions as in `while(std::cin>>std::noskipws>>buffer && !std::cin.eof() && buffer != '\n')` ?

Comment: @Walter Because I won't be able to read then files with multiple lines...

Comment: this code seems highly dangerous as you try to read (in some cases) multiple characters in a single char (buffer-overflow)

Comment: @Sim Yeah, but it just looks like. Because what happens is that it loops though the whole input and puts one char into buffer after the other. So there won't be any multiple chars getting pressed into one char.

Answer (score 2):

You could require the input to always end EOF (meaning from commmand line requiring `^D` to be pressed) and then use the process for b as always. This would then enable multiline input from cmdline as well

Comment: I could require that, but what if I can't?
(What is the keystroke for ^D in linux shell/windows 'shell'?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the (old) [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) function, which takes a pointer to a char array and can use a delimiter. But you wont be able to ensure that in every case it will read to the eof (as the char buffer might be too small), but using a char-array and not paying attention to the size of it is a very dangerous (and from the point of security catastrophic) thing anyways as it can lead to [buffer-overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) which can be easily exploited.

This code should enable you to extract line by line from the input:

```
char buffer[256];
while(getline(buffer,256,'\n')) { //get a line
   /* do something with the line */
}
```

This to read a maximum amount of chars:

```
char buffer[256];
while(getline(buffer,256)) {//get a maximum amount out of the input
   /* do something with the line */
}
```