# How to put EOF(end of file ) in code::blocks?

Tags: c++, eof

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int grade,
        aCount = 0,
        bCount = 0,
        cCount = 0,
        dCount = 0,
        fCount = 0;

    cout << "Enter the letter grades." << endl
        << "Enter the EOF character to end input." << endl;

    while ( ( grade = cin.get() ) != EOF ) {

        switch ( grade ) {

            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                ++aCount;
                break;

            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                ++bCount;
                break;

            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                ++cCount;
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                ++dCount;
                break;

            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                ++fCount;
                break;

            case '\n':
            case '\t':
            case ' ':
                break;

                    default:
                        cout << "Incorrect letter grade entered."
                            << " Enter a new grade." << endl;
                        break;

        }
    }    

    cout << "\n\nTotal for each letter grade are:"
         << "\nA: " << aCount
         << "\nB: " << bCount
         << "\nC: " << cCount
         << "\nD: " << dCount
         << "\nF: " << fCount << endl;

                return 0;
}
```

I build and run this and it says "EOF has not been declared" at line 19 i.e. the line with the while header. I typed the exact codes one by one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Code::Blocks

Comment: `while ( ( grade = cin.get() ) != EOF )` Tell me where did you learn/read that this is how to use C++ I/O streams?

Comment: get() doesn't return EOF - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: Look into [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) for a friendly, cross-platform C++ GUI library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, it does, at least for the `char` version. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234171/how-to-read-from-stdcin-until-the-end-of-the-stream

Comment: this is the exact code written in my course book which is C++ HOW TO PROGRAM 9th Edition

Answer (score 1):

The `EOF` macro is defined in the `cstdio`, but it’s usually better to use C++-style IO than C-style IO. Instead of checking the return value to see if it’s `EOF`, it’s better to check `cin.eofbit` (or, since other problems are possible, the `cin.failbit`). You can check the `failbit` of a stream by trying to evaluate it as a `bool`, as below.

If you replace your while loop with a for loop, as

```
for (char grade = cin.get(); cin; grade = cin.get()) {
```

it should work better (in this case you should also get rid of the initial `grade` declaration, since it is only used in the loop and should be declared there).

EDIT:

This can be simplified further. The [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) method supports passing in a character reference, so you can call `cin.get(grade)` instead of `grade = cin.get()`. The advantage of this is that, when passed a character reference, `get` returns a copy of the stream, so you can do the read and check the state at the same time. Using this method, you need to declare `grade` in advance, but the loop can start with

```
while (cin.get(grade)) {
```

Comment: You could take one step further and arrive to the usual C++ input loop`while(cin.get(grade)) { ...`

Comment: Oh, you’re right. I haven’t done character-by-character input in while.

Answer (score -2):

```
while ( ( grade = cin.get() ) != EOF ) {
```

In the above line you are only taking the grade as input.
There should be a `cin.get()` for EOF also,unless it will not work.
When you are doing this you need to declare EOF first as char, as in the above line the comparison is in between two characters.

Comment: EOF is supposed to mean the end of file. It doesn’t make sense for it to be taken as input.

Comment: there should be a file to start with in c++ and since there is no file streams or files declared the eof should act as char not as end of file.

Comment: Standard input, which is what `cin` refers to, acts like a file in C++ even if it isn’t a regular on-disk file.

Comment: But the file should be declared explicitly in order to get EOF

Comment: What do you mean by declaring the file explicitly?

Comment: i mean if there is to get a `EOF` then there should be a file to start with and if the file is not declared then it won't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be a compiler error, where the `EOF` constant isn’t defined. If it were defined (correctly), then there would be no problem with `cin.get()` returning it. I still don’t know what you mean by “declaring” a file.

Comment: I mean the stream for the file like `fstream openfile("filename.txt");`.Then we can get `openfile.eof()`.

Comment: The `eof()` function is [available on all IO streams, not just std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), and this includes the standard `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`. It also is not the same thing as the all-caps `EOF` macro in the question.